# Are 'robot' and 'droid' used interchangeably?

Tags: star-wars, droids, terminology

In Episode IV, after Luke is rescued from the Sand People by Ben Kenobi, he refers to C-3PO and R2-D2 as *robots* rather than *droids*. This struck me as odd as the latter seems to be the preferred term throughout the series. Is this use of *robot* a one-off or perhaps a mistake?

Comment: I always thought Droid was short for Android, which is a robot with a human like form.  That would apply to C-3PO but not R2-D2, even though they have both been referred to as droids.

Comment: @Monty129 I'm more curious as to how they were both referred to as _robots_. AFAIK, the scene mentioned in my question is the only one where the two droids are called _robots_. I'm curious to know if this is the only time this happens in the entire series.

Comment: Since it happens early in the movie, it could be simply to help viewers understand that these were mechanical automata of some sort -- if they had immediately jumped in to using "Droids" some people may have been more confused. I'm not sure how familiar the average movie-goer of the day would have been with the concept. Still, I'm just speculating.

Comment: Originally, the word "android" (from which "droid" is obviously derived), meant simply "man-like" - andro-man, oid-in the form of. The word "cardioid", meaning "heart-shaped" is another example of this kind of word. So if you said "an android robot", it would mean a robot in the shape of a man. By this definition, C3PO is an android, but R2-D2 is not. But that's not the in-universe usage.

Comment: I've wondered this my whole life!!!! Still waiting for a satisfactory answer. I feel that Luke saying robots destroys the world-building because, besides that 1 instance, ROBOT is not a Star Wars thing.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens: "a robot in the shape of a man. By this definition, C3PO is an android, but R2-D2 is not." - that is debatable. It could well be argued that R2-D2 has an (albeit very crude) approximation of a "head" (with an eye!), a "torso", and then either two "arms" and one "leg"/"foot", or just two "legs". Looking at it this way, C-3PO is certainly more man-like in shape than R2-D2, but R2-D2 in turn is still quite a bit more man-like in shape than e.g. nowadays' assembly line robots (which are e.g. just a multi-jointed arm with a specific tool). ...

Comment: ... Then of course, Star Wars shows a multi-species universe. The idea of what is "a man" and thus the typical shape of one may be considerably more varied than it is for us (thinking e.g. of Sebulba or Jabba).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it depends on how strictly you draw the definition of "man-shaped".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Through the six existing scripts, the only instance I can find any of the *characters* referring to them as "robots" is Luke in ANH:

> LUKE: If they traced the robots here, they may have learned who they
>   sold them to. And that would lead them home!

All other dialog refers to them as "droids".

Interestingly, the scripts for the original trilogy refer to them as "robots" in the script in all non-verbal instances. The prequel trilogy, however, refers to them as "droids" in all instances.

This development can probably be attributed to the fact that the term **droid** is trademarked by Lucasfilm, LTD.

Comment: The term **Droid** may be trademarked by Lucasfilm, but it was first used (as far as the OED knows) in a 1952 sci-fi [story](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31611) by Mari Wolf.

Comment: @user14111 my point was more that Lucas needs to continue to use the trademarked term as appropriate whenever possible at the risk of the mark becoming diluted to the point that they lose the claim on it.

Comment: I had no point at all, I was just making an off-topic comment. (That is permitted, isn't it?) I just thought it was kind of interesting that someone had used the word "droid" long before Star Wars.

Answer (score 8):

All droids are robots, but not all robots are droids. Robot is superset of Droid. Saying C3P0 and R2D2 robots is correct, but less precise. Its like calling a car a "vehicle" instead of just a car (thanks @ValekHalfHeart for the example).

Official (LucasFilm) definition of Droid: "A mechanical being with a self-aware consciousness, as distinguished from a computer by having a self-contained method of locomotion."

Comment: Rather than the definition of _droid_, I'm interested in the definition and usage of _robot_ in the Star Wars  universe. From my comment above, "I'm more curious as to how they were both referred to as robots. AFAIK, the scene mentioned in my question is the only one where the two droids are called robots. I'm curious to know if this is the only time this happens in the entire series."

Comment: @coleopterist It would be like calling a car a "vehicle" instead of just a car. It's still true, just less precise and used less often.

Comment: @coleopterist Updated the answer with more clarification..

Comment: @coleopterist according to the scripts, there is only one scene where they are verbally called "robots" by characters, but the script refers to them as "robots" throughout.

Comment: @phantom42 Thanks. Please expand your comment into an answer. I notice that you have used the singular _script_; how about the other episodes?

Answer (score 3):

In *Star Wars Rebels*, season 1 episode 6, at 21:16, we can infer that Ezra is referring to C11OP (Chopper) as a 'robot' rather than a droid with the line:

> No grumpy robots [in reference to Chopper], no smelly Lasats [in reference to Garazeb/Zeb]... it's good to be back.

So it's not exclusive to the scene mentioned, but 'droid' is generally much more preferred, it seems. I believe I also heard somewhere that droids were referred to as robots once in *The Clone Wars* as well, by Anakin Skywalker, but I don't remember which episode or the video which told me about this.